# How to detect that a bound property's value has changed in angular 4

Tags: angular

This is how you detect that a property decorated with @Input has changed:

```
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() message: string;
  startDate: Date;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
     for (let propName in changes) {  
        let change = changes[propName];
        if (propName === 'message') {
          //do something...
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Here's the markup

```
<app-date-picker [(model)]="startDate"></app-date-picker>
```

*startDate* is not decorated by `@Input`, but I'd like to do something if the value of startDate changes.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the (onChanged) event on the date picker as follows,

```
<app-date-picker [(model)]="startDate" (onChanged)="onDateChanged()"></app-date-picker>
```

and in **`TS`**,

```
 onDateChanged() {
     access the changes here 
 }
```

Comment: So there's no other mechanism other than relying on `onChange` event?

Comment: that s the recommended way to do, why you are looking for other ways/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
<app-date-picker [(model)]="startDate" (modelChange)='dateChanged($event)'></app-date-picker>
```

reason for using `(modelChange)` is simple , `[(model)]` uses two way data binding for the variable bound . So i can use `[model]` and `(modelChange)` .

The Other way is mentioned by @Sajeetharan . So Choose whichever you want .
Let me know if this works.